For a PFC Boost converter, how significant is front end EMI filter damping?
Power converters are said to have a negative dynamic input resistance as long as the control loop is active( ie, within the gain crossover frequnecy).

Since the voltage control loop of PFC converters are slow ( gain cross over is in the range of 10-20Hz), wouldn't the input impedance of converter be anyways high and positive (at close to filter resonant frequency)? I have a pretty high value of PFC inductor (1.2mH).
Do I neeed to really worry so much about EMI filter damping for PFC boost converter around the resonant frequencies?

The incremental resistance of a converter operated in closed-loop is negative at low frequency, where the open-loop gain is high. What matters is to look at the angle of the EMI filter output impedance and the PFC input impedance when conditions for oscillations are met, that is to say if there is an overlap between the two magnitudes. At the points where overlaps occur, the minor loop had a unity "gain" and the angle now matters. You can check answer on SE here.

It wouldn't be very good PFC if (from a moment-to-moment basis) current had that relationship :)

@VerbalKint: i completely understood the need for impedance seperation between EMI filter and converter. My doubt is wouldn't it be inherent in a PFC boost converter ( due to the reasons above)?
The linked ans says: "On the contrary, current-mode-controlled converters (the basic cells) naturally exhibit a negative incremental input resistance even in open-loop conditions."- Iam just wondering if this would overthrow my assumptions abt converter impedance since my PFC is avg current mode controlled. I was expecting the open loop impedance to be high (due to high boost inductor) and positive.
